# Filter items from two different APIs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one API returning two arrays - one returning category name, category id. And another returning food name and category id.
I need to map and render food according to the categories. Eg: Coke comes under Category beverage (category id 2).

How can I map and find which category and render it according?

**Sample Category API :**

```
{
"id": 1,
"en_description": "Beverage",
"en_org_description": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"en_description": "Wine",
"en_org_description": null
},
{
"id": 3,
"en_description": "By the Glass",
"en_org_description": null
}
```

**Sample Food API:**

```
{
"id": 1,
"category_id": 11,
"en_name": "The Bethany",
"en_description": "",
"price": 12,
"picture_url": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"category_id": 14,
"en_name": "Special French",
"en_description": "",
"price": 17,
"picture_url": null
},
{
"id": 3,
"category_id": 7,
"en_name": "Three Creeks IPA",
"en_description": "",
"price": 6,
"picture_url": null
},
{
"id": 4,
"category_id": 6,
"en_name": "Kids Cheeseburger",
"en_description": "",
"price": 9,
"picture_url": null
}
```

I need to map them accordingly instead of manually typed

**Code:**

```
function BottomContainer() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://api-dev.souszen.com/location_and_menus?location_id=119&user_id=151"
      );
      // console.log(response.data.menus);
      setCategories(response.data.categories);
      // console.log(response.data.categories);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // console.log(categories[0].en_description);

  return (
    <div className="mt-16">
      <MenuItems />

      {categories.map((category) => (
        <div key={category.id}>
          <p className="text-3xl font-semibold ml-4 mt-5">
            {category.en_description}
          </p>
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
          <FoodList name="California Roll" price="4.99" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can see only one API. Is this returning both the arrays?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes, Its one api returning 2 different arrays

Comment: `beverage` is category 1. Isn't wine a beverage? Why does it need its own category?

Comment: you can create a new array with categories and their food items as children and then use map to render.

Comment: @Andy Dude, Nevermind about that. Its a sample array. And My goal is to map it with the category id

Comment: We're trying to help _you_. If you don't make your example code make sense, how can we make sense of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{categories.map((category) => (
    <div key={category.id}>
      <p className="text-3xl font-semibold ml-4 mt-5">
        {category.en_description}
      </p>
      {foods.map((food)=>{
          if(food.category_id===category.id)
          {
              <FoodList name={food.en_name} price={food.price} />
           }
      }}
    </div>
  ))}
```

For each category, you can iterate in foods array and check if they share the same category id then return that div

Comment: It worked ! But, i get a warning "Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function" . I tried doing  " return  <FoodList name={food.en_name} price={food.price} /> " But dint solve the warning.

Comment: You can ignore that warning, but if you want to resolve it just add a return statement after the end of the if block
`if(food.category_id===category.id){<FoodList name={food.en_name} price{food.price} />}return 0;`

Comment: I Can't do return 0; As it renders n number of 0s in the screen.

Comment: Can you try just `return;` in your code and see if that works